# HyperLedger-downloading Platform-specific Binaries on Windows 10

Tags: curl, hyperledger-fabric

I'll trying to setup Hyperledger sample on Windows 10 using the 1.1 documentation.

I've installed all the prerequisites.

but we I run this command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
```

from within the fabric-sample folder, I get this error:

> ===> Downloading platform specific fabric binaries   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100  1049    0  1049    0     0   1049      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>   --:--:--  1722
>
> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>   ===> Downloading platform specific fabric-ca-client binary   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100  1076    0  1076    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  1:11:35
>   --:--:--  1465
>
> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>
> ------> 1.1.0 fabric-ca-client binary is not available to download  (Avaialble from 1.1.0-rc1) <----

curl verison: curl-7.59.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying the above comand in powershell. Try executing in git bash.

Comment: yes, I was using Powershell. git bash worked. but do you why powershell is not working? It worked with powershell on a co-workers machine.