# HyperLedger Fabric Samples - Downloading Platform specific fabric binaries on windows 10

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am installing the Fabric-Samples from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/install.html on windows 10.

When I try to run the command, `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s`, I am getting an error in downloading the binaries. Please find the dump from the terminal below. I am running this from the fabric-samples folder where the cloning is done.

```
Clone hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Checking out v2.0.0 of hyperledger/fabric-samples
error: pathspec 'v2.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git

Pull Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 2.0.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.0.0/hyperledger-fabric-msys_nt-10.0-18362-amd64-2.0.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     t0 a r . e x e0:   E r r o r0  o-p-e:n-i-n:g- -a r-c-:h-i-v:e-:-  F-a-i:l-e-d: -t-o   o p e n0 '\\.\tape0'
100     9  100     9    0     0      9      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--     4
(23) Failed writing body
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 2.0.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

But when I run this in Git-Cmd(as suggested in [HyperLedger-downloading Platform-specific Binaries on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445375/hyperledger-downloading-platform-specific-binaries-on-windows-10?rq=1)), I get the following:

```
Clone hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Checking out v2.0.0 of hyperledger/fabric-samples
error: pathspec 'v2.0.0' did not match any file(s) known to git

Pull Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 2.0.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.0.0/hyperledger-fabric-windows-amd64-2.0.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0tar.exe: Error opening archive: Failed to open '\\.\tape0'
100   656  100   656    0     0    328      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   244
  0 64.3M    0 16943    0     0   2420      0  7:44:40  0:00:07  7:44:33  3929
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 2.0.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

I created /bin and /config folders in the fabric-samples folder. Pls let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean you created the bin and config folders ? . when you download the binaries from the curl command , the bin file is generated in fabric-samples folder.
All you have to do is create a folder for your binaries - cmd into it and run the curl command

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the latest Fabric version explicitly:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 2.1.0`